Animating hover - delay underline until hover animation finishes
I'm encountering an issue with implementing a hover effect on underlined links using SCSS. I'm aiming to create a transition where, on hover, the text color changes to red, and the underline disappears momentarily before being redrawn in red from left to right. When hover finishes first the red underline should dissapear and only then the original, black underline should appear again (without animation). The first step works, however, I'm having trouble ensuring that the transition from the hovered element finishes before the non-hovered element is displayed. I've tried experimenting with transition-delay but to no avail. You can see the issue in the following code - notice how black underline appears BEFORE the red line completely shrinks when hover ends (on mouse leave). Can you help?


a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
<a href="google.com">My link to Google</a>




Sounds like you need an animation rather than a transition.

I've tried to play with animation but haven't figured that out either

Set transition-delay to a text-decoration-color in normal state:


a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  color: black;
  transition: color 0.3s, text-decoration-color 0s 0.3s;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s;
}

a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
<a href="google.com">My link to Google</a>




For the effect you want to achieve, first set text-decoration:none in the a selector.
Then, for the underline when not hovering add pseudo after element:


a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:10;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

a::after {
   content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 0s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover::after {
  width: 0%;
}
<a href="google.com">My link to Google</a>



I've added transition-delay to wait for the red line to disappear. Also, z-index in the before element so that when link is hovered it doesn't stay hidden under the after element.
You can delay the transition of after element to happen exactly when you want or you can also start transition from right:0 for giving the loading bar effect.

This meets the second requirement, but misses the increasing length on hover (the first part). I need something that will merge your code with mine.

@Malvinka you asked for black line to appear after the hover event is removed and red lines finishes its transition, what else am i missing?

You can do the wished effect (kinda) using the opacity aka color of the text-decoration.
when the a tag is hoverd, you can set the following:
text-decoration: underline transparent;
with adding the transition:
text-decoration 0.9s ease;
in the a tag styling. ( set the wished length instead of 0.9s
this does have the side effect of the underline can be seen a bit when the red line is shown, im sure you can play around with the idea to find a fix for that issue.
here is a snippet to test:


a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  transition: text-decoration 0.9s ease;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline transparent;
  color: red;
}

a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
<a href="google.com">My link to Google</a>



